# iphone simulator crash

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, calayer

My app crashes only in simulator , it doesn't crash on device.

it crashes in simulator and gives me nothing except this :

```
  #0    0x00000000 in 0x00000000 ()
    #1  0x0182966e in icu::RuleBasedBreakIterator::handleNext ()
    #2  0x018293dc in icu::RuleBasedBreakIterator::next() ()
    #3  0x01828a12 in icu::RuleBasedBreakIterator::following(int) ()
    #4  0x043378dd in WebCore::nextBreakablePosition(unsigned short const*, int, int, bool) ()
    #5  0x04cc2fca in -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:letterSpacing:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:renderedStringOut:] ()
    #6  0x04cc07be in -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:letterSpacing:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:] ()
    #7  0x04cc0499 in -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:] ()
    #8  0x04cc021b in -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_sizeInRect:withFont:ellipsis:lineSpacing:] ()
    #9  0x0053fc33 in -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:lineSpacing:] ()
    #10 0x00644987 in -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] ()
    #11 0x006422fc in -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] ()
    #12 0x00559187 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] ()
    #13 0x00221b5e in -[CALayer drawInContext:] ()
    #14 0x0022de47 in backing_callback(CGContext*, void*) ()
    #15 0x0017b1f7 in CABackingStoreUpdate ()
    #16 0x0022dd24 in -[CALayer _display] ()
    #17 0x0022427d in CALayerDisplayIfNeeded ()
    #18 0x001c90c3 in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
    #19 0x001ca294 in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
    #20 0x001ca555 in CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) ()
    #21 0x98f4de0c in _pthread_tsd_cleanup ()
    #22 0x98f0664c in _pthread_exit ()
    #23 0x98f069a0 in pthread_exit ()
    #24 0x00c93d1a in -[NSString compare:options:] ()
    #25 0x00c93c98 in __NSThread__main__ ()
    #26 0x98f04ed9 in _pthread_start ()
    #27 0x98f086de in thread_start ()
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also explain what sort of actions you were doing when it crashes, and what iOS version of the sim?

Comment: Does your app have multiple threads?

Comment: yes I have multiple threads, and I have a webview which shows an html., iOS version is 4.3

Answer (score 1):

Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace `0x543216` with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

[See this article for more detailed instructions.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

---

Another idea is to try turning off auto-correction in the simulator Settings App.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide details about what you are doing in the App right before the crash?